# Python, cvzone - why do i get this ValueError?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, gesture-recognition, cvzone

I am trying to zoom into a picture with usage of two hands (gesture controled image zoom), but when trying to use two hands I get this error but I don't know why. When making my program I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPaFV3QBsEw&t=675s. It's strange because the program worked for him.

This is the error I get:

```
  hands, img = detector.findHands(img)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This is my code:

```
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
 
detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.7)
startDist = None
scale = 0
cx, cy = 500,500

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img)
    img1 = cv2.imread("kung_fu_panda.png")
 
    if len(hands) == 2:
        
        if detector.fingersUp(hands[0]) == [1, 1, 0, 0, 0] and \
                detector.fingersUp(hands[1]) == [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]:
         
            lmList1 = hands[0]["lmList"]
            lmList2 = hands[1]["lmList"]
            # point 8 is the tip of the index finger
            if startDist is None:
                length, info, img = detector.findDistance(hands[0]["center"], hands[1]["center"], img)
                startDist = length
 
            length, info, img = detector.findDistance(hands[0]["center"], hands[1]["center"], img)
 
            scale = int((length - startDist) // 2)
            cx, cy = info[4:]
            print(scale)
    else:
        startDist = None
 
    try:
        h1, w1, _= img1.shape
        newH, newW = ((h1+scale)//2)*2, ((w1+scale)//2)*2
        img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (newW,newH))
 
        img[cy-newH//2:cy+ newH//2, cx-newW//2:cx+ newW//2] = img1
    except:
        pass
 
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Try `print(detector.findHands(img))` and `len(detector.findHands(img))`, what output do you see?

Comment: The source code of the `findHands` method is [here](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/blob/master/cvzone/HandTrackingModule.py#L40). And it should indeed return two items back. Do what kinskukdua suggested and check to see if your version of the library is older with `cvzone.__version__`. Also use `help(detector.findHands)` to see its documentation to see its argument signature and what it returns.

Comment: when i used len(detector.findHands(img)) the output was 480

Comment: and the version I am using is cvzone==1.4.1, because newest versions don't have HandTrackingModule option which I need for easyer making of other projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvzone library keeps updating their library every time. As you can see at the beginning of the video, when he imports the cvzone package he uses cvzone version 1.5.0.

I tried your code with other versions and got an error similar to yours but with version 1.5.0 your code worked great.

you can use [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296432/cant-find-findposition-attributeerror-handdetector-object-has-no-attribute/69300598#69300598) to change the version of your cvzone library in your project to 1.5.0.

Comment: I am using version 1.4.1 because I need it for other projects. Because they removed HandTrackingModule  option from 1.5.0, are there any chances so that my code vould work for my version?

Comment: no, you will have to separate the functions from the original code of cvzone to 2 different methods..